# Sending integers to a method

Tags: java, methods, parameters, integer

so when I compile and run the application, I get the prompts for the integers then nothing after that. Am I not correctly sending the integers to the method, multiplynumbers():?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MultiplyNVRM2
{
  private static int one=0;

  private static int two=0;

  private static int product =one * two;



  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("%nPlease enter an integer: ");

       one = input.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("%nPlease enter another integer: ");

       two = input.nextInt();

       input.nextLine();

        multiplyNumbers();


  }//end main()

  public static  int mulitplyNumbers()
  {

      product =  one *  two;

   System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d", int one, int two, product);


  }//end multiplyingNumbers
}
```

Comment: This `System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d", int one, int two, product);` isn't legal code.

Comment: Also, you aren't 'sending' any integers to the function. You're simply calling a function which uses the values of the variables one and two.

Comment: I suggest you a) make the code compile, b) tidy up the code with your code formatter, c) I suggest you pass the values as arguments, not static fields.

Comment: Any standard IDE like Eclipse would instantly give you an error for writing System.out.printf();

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
public static void mulitplyNumbers(int one, int two) {
    int product = one * two;
    System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d", one, two, product);
}
```

And please remember:

- If your code doesn't return anything, use the key word `void` instead of `int`. Note you print the result out and dont use it anymore.
- Arguments in `System.out.printf` and any other method doesnt require to initialite their type while calling that method.
- Use your integers as parameters. You can call the method in the `main` one with:

  ```
  multipleNumbers(one, two);
  ```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please concider to accept the best answer here that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

This line is invalid:

```
System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d", int one, int two, product);
```

you can not use the word int in the parameter of the method `printf` because you are not declaring any method.... you are CALLING it...

try instead

```
 System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d", one, two, product);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%n%d * %d = %d",one,two, product);
```